# error in wordpress wp-includes core files

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress 4.7.5 installation, which is giving me this error:

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at xxxxxxxxx\wp-includes\script-loader.php:1328) in
>   xxxxxxxwp-includes\rest-api.php on line 513

And in my traffic stats, I see a lot of reports of page loading delays.

I looked for solutions and tried them all, even replacing those 2 files with new versions, but the warning stays. I don't know what else to do.

Any ideas?
This is the site: https://lalulula.tv/

Comment: Backup DB. Disable all plugins. Change to default theme. Does it still happen?

Comment: Another troubleshooting step you can try is checking the date/time of the error messages, and comparing it to your site's "access log", if your host provides it. I think it's strange for the rest API to be serving content when the script loader is being used, but it could be the plugin or theme calling `_print_styles()` incorrectly.